# Import OS module won't import in Pycharm

Tags: python-import

Import os module won't import in Pycharm. I've read that it's already built in and that it doesn't need to be downloaded. Has anyone else had this issue and found a fix?

Comment: Do you have an error message?

Comment: Hi Jacob! I don't get an error message. I just type in "import os" and Pycharm just underlines it. Pycharm then says "Unused import statement". Does that help? I'm new to Python.

Comment: My understanding is that I don't have to install this module, but Pycharm is not recognizing it for some reason.

Comment: Unused import statement just means you haven't made use of the library within your code. It's not an actual error, just a warning.

If you write the rest of your code, it will be fine.

Comment: Thanks Jacob and that did the trick!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Would you mind accepting my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unused import statement just means you haven't made use of the library within your code. It's not an actual error, just a warning. If you write the rest of your code, it will be fine.